MUI Data Grid filter on column rendered with Chips
How to enable to filter on column that is using chips to display "tags" of given row.
It is what I'm using to generate chips
getCategoriesChips(categories) {
    let chips = []
    Object.keys(categories).forEach((key) => {
        chips.push(<Chip key={key} label={categories[key]} size="small" onClick={() => 
            this.categoryClick(categories[key])}/>)
    })
    return chips
}

And here is how my render cell code looks
renderCell: params => (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', gap: 0.5 }}>
        {this.getCategoriesChips(params.row.categories)}
    </Box>
)

But even if column is enabled for filtering entering any value clears my data grid
Do I need to write valueGetter?
